# how to Download Azure PublishSetting file for a specific subscription

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have more than one Azure Subscription with my account, when I try to download the PublisheSetting file thru PowerShell, it is downloading the setting file for one of the subscription, I'm unable to find an option to force download the publishsetting file for a specific subscription.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Allegedly the web interface should prompt you to choose which subscription you want to download the file for. Are you seeing that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it always download settings for all your subscription. Same from below UI, there is no options for user to specific subscription

https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings

Comment: When I tried, it just downloads for one of the subscription in my list and not for all.

Comment: that is interesting, do you have multiple AD Tenant? for me when i go to that page, i got one XML that contains all my subscription.